# Enter BIOS on Centos6 ran into virtualbox

Tags: centos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, bios

I have a windows 10 host machine.

On this host, I am running a `Centos6` in `virtual box 6.1`.

In this Guest, I have `vagrant 2.7` and `virtualbox 6.1`. My purpose is to do [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Quick+Start+Guide) tutorial.

However, when running the command `./up.sh 1`, I have the following error (sorry, no copy paste available between host and guest):

[image]

According to others questions with the same problem, it is because VT-x is not enabled in BIOS.

---

**How to access `BIOS` on `Centos6` run via `virtualbox` ?**

Comment: You need to enable VT-X in your computer's BIOS, not on the VM's BIOS (which you can't access anyway, AFAIK).

Comment: Ah. Problematic. I don't want to mess with office laptop. Isn't there any other way ? @Renan

Comment: AFAIK there is no other way since virtualbox uses VT-x. Also just turning on VT-x wouldn't mess with the system, it will just enable you to run VMs.